# Using {gtsummary} to display confidence intervals for survey.design object?

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

`{gtsummary}` has the `tbl_svysummary()` function for producing summary statistics tables from survey.design objects created  by the `{survey}` package. The `{gtsummary}` [website](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/gallery.html) provides an example of how to add confidence intervals for `tbl_summary()`, by defining custom functions for calculating CIs which are then passed to the `statistics =`  argument in `tbl_summary()`.

However, the documentation for `tbl_svysummary()` noted that "Unlike tbl_summary(), it is not possible to pass a custom function." I'm using a survey.design object since I'm applying weighting to my data, but I really like the output of `{gtsummary}`, so it would be great if I could find a way to add confidence intervals as I need to show these for reporting.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this, or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to report that it is currently not possible. The way one would go about it using the `add_stat()` function (example here [How to generate effect size [90%CI] in the summary table using R package “gtsummary”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137514/how-to-generate-effect-size-90ci-in-the-summary-table-using-r-package-gtsumm)). But that function has not yet been generalized to work with `tbl_svysummary()` objects.

I had never considered generalizing it until now, so thank you very much for your question. I opened a GitHub Issue to track implementation progress. You can subscribe to the issue to be notified when it is complete.
https://github.com/ddsjoberg/gtsummary/issues/688

Happy Programming!

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the quick response. Great to hear that it's something that might be implemented in the future - I was pleasantly surprised to find that there was already some support for survey.design objects, so would be great to see the functionality be expanded for tbl_svysummary()