# Using gtsummary() to create custom table for survey design objects

Tags: r, survey, gtsummary

I've been using `gtsummary` for to create custom tables for publications and reports, and it has been a great experience so far. However, I've recently hit a wall. I don't have a lot of experience using survey design objects with `gtsummary` and `tbl-svysummary`. I have to create a table format that has proportions with CI in one column, totals in the other and risk difference with CI in the last column.

I have created a reproducible example data with what I have achieved so far.

```
set.seed(123) 
n <- 800
dat <- data.frame(id=1:n, 
                  group.var=rep(LETTERS[1:2], n/2),
                  age=sample(18:48, n, replace=TRUE),
                  var1=factor(sample(paste("Category", rep(1:5, 1)), n, 
                  replace=TRUE)),
                  var2=factor(sample(paste("Property", rep(1:2, 1)), n,                                     
                  replace=TRUE)),
                  var3=factor(sample(paste("Source", rep(1:3, 1)), n, 
                  replace=TRUE)),
                  var4=rnorm(n),
                  cluster=factor(sample(paste("Cluster", rep(1:26, 1)), n, replace=TRUE)))
library(srvyr)
svy.dat <- dat |>
  as_survey_design(ids = cluster)

# I created the following code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137514/how-to-generate-effect-size-90ci-in-the-summary-table-using-r-package-gtsumm).
rdiff <- function(data, var, by) {
  outcome = "Category 1"
  dat$v <- dat |> select(all_of(var)) |> deframe()
  dat$v <- as.numeric(dat$v == "Category 1")
  
  svy.dat <- dat |> as_survey_design(ids = cluster)
  
  # Risk Difference
  rd.obj <- avg_comparisons(svyglm(as.formula(paste(var, "~", by)), design = svy.dat)) 
          #Right now the as.formula() does not work with this command. 
          #The only way it works is when I replace as.formula(paste(var,"~", by)) 
          #with v ~ group, which makes this function useless if I want to 
          #compare the risk difference across other grouping variables, on 
          #top of it being able to calculate risk difference and CI one 
          #category at a time per variable.
  
  # Formatting risk difference and ci
  est <- style_sigfig(rd.obj$estimate*100)
  l.ci <- style_sigfig(rd.obj$conf.low*100)
  u.ci <- style_sigfig(rd.obj$conf.high*100)
  
  # returning estimate with CI together
  str_glue("{est} ({l.ci}, {u.ci})")
}

rdiff(data = dat, var = "var1", by = "group.var)
#The output of this function should be 7.8 (3.2, 12)
```

I could probably get the proportion with CI from `gtsummary`. However, I'm having trouble packaging all this to create a table with the following format.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiTVT.png)

I'd really appreciate it if anyone could help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of problems with your `rdiff` function (I'm only going to answer that question, not your other questions)

First, I find it suspicious that you are passing in a `data` argument but then modifying a data frame called `dat` that isn't an argument. I think the references to `dat` in the function should be `data`.

You can't refer to the variable you created as `var1`, because when you created it you called it `v`. The solution here is not to create a new variable

I would do the variable substitution like this

```
rdiff <- function(data, var, by) {
  outcome = "Category 1"
   
  svy.dat <- data |> as_survey_design(ids = cluster)
  
  formula<- bquote(I(.(as.name(var)) == .(outcome)) ~ .(as.name(by)))
  # Risk Difference
  rd.obj <-svyglm(formula, design = svy.dat)

coef(rd.obj)
}
```

which works

```
> rdiff(data = dat, var = "var1", by = "group.var")
(Intercept)  group.varB 
     0.2175     -0.0075
```

If you look at the object `formula`, it is `I(var1 == "Category 1") ~ group.var`. The `.()` syntax evaluates what is inside it, so we evaluate `"var"` as `var1`, evaluate `outcome` as `"Category 1"`, and evaluate `by` as `"group.var"`. We also use `as.name` to convert strings to names.  Using `bquote` is more flexible than `as.formula` because it works on *expressions* rather than just on character strings. You could probably use tidyverse quasiquotation instead if you really wanted to.

Finally, as a note for the future, it helps if your reproducible example *actually runs*, rather than us having to work out which packages to install and load. Your example also doesn't run because it's missing a quotation mark in the call to `rdiff`.